# add copy and popup function in jquery snippet plugin

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, code-snippets

I am using jquery snippet to display code snippet as is on the site
http://steamdev.com/snippet/

In the examples given, on hover, one has the option to copy, turn to text/html and popup  the code.

I have managed to style the code but I do not get the option.. How do I do it.

Below is my code

```
$("pre.htmlcode").snippet("html");
```

Comment: In their doc they talk of a param `clipboard`, who needs to be fill with the ZeroClipboard.swf file path, have you tried to set it?

Comment: Yes, it does not work

Comment: Can you provide us some code, or a jsfiddle?

Comment: It works when I put it on jsfiddle

Comment: The problem is probably elsewhere in your code, can you give us a link or a part of your code?